# Redash MongoDB query by ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, objectid, redash

I have a collection with the following document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58aa706c658d1dc6c700002c"),
    "source" : "web",
    "type" : "Comentarios",
    "email" : "jhondoe@xyz.com",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-02-20T04:28:28.623Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-02-20T04:28:28.623Z")
}
```

I need to build a query in **Redash Syntax** to get a document by '_id'. I built the following query but always I got an error: "Invalid query format. The query is not a valid JSON."

```
{
    "collection": "commerce_messages",
    "query" : {
        "_id": "ObjectId(58aa706c658d1dc6c700002c)"
    }
}
```

I tried enclosing the ObjectId on quotes but the query does not return results.

The only documentation I have found about this is in this link: https://redash.io/help/queries/querying_mongodb.html but they do not explain how to query for ObjectId.

Comment: Maybe try with the MongoDB Extended JSON notation for [object ids](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid).

Comment: @MarcTarin Thanks, I tried with your suggestion and works

Answer (score 8):

The redash [FAQ for querying MongoDB](https://redash.io/help/queries/querying_mongodb.html) claims they support [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

The syntax to query by ObjectId is:

```
{
    "collection": "commerce_messages",
    "query": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58aa706c658d1dc6c700002c"
        }
    }
}
```